# Behaviour of Nemytskii operator wtr weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence, nonlinear-analysis

Let $N_f$ denote the Nemytskii operator and suppose that $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is true that $$ N_f(u_n)\rightharpoonup N_f(u)?$$
And if it is true, in what space we have the weak convergence? Any help or references are well accepted!